# Running a program that read a file and count the characters in the file results in FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I'm trying to read a file and count the number of characters within file. Below is my code. However, whenever I run the code, NetBeans always output the following error message:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\TestData\data.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at test.Count.main(Count.java:28)
C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Why is this happening? Is there something I'm missing?

Location of Count.java file is `C:\Test\src\test\Count.java`

```
import java.io.*;

public class Count {

    public static void countChars(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        int count = 0;

        while (in.read() != -1) {
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("Counted " + count + " chars.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        countChars(new FileInputStream("C:\\TestData\\data.txt"));

    }
}
```

Location of data.txt is  `C:\TestData\`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a relative path here?

Comment: What I noted in the exception is that it references `C:\TestData\data` while you specify `C:\\TestData\\data.txt`.

Comment: You are probably missing the .txt extension.

Comment: @uniknow I have run the program with C:\\TestData\\data.txt as the input to FileInputStream constructor and it still results in an exception, but this time it is referencing to C:\TestData\data.txt

Comment: Could you try with c:/TestData/data.txt, and can you check whether the file is public accessible.

Comment: Well it may be due to permission issue. Try the same in `D:`.

Comment: Please paste the output of running the following: `File f = new File("C:\\TestData\\data.txt");
  System.out.printf("Exists: %b\n", f.exists());
  System.out.printf("Can read: %b", f.canRead());`

Comment: I believe in the document is data.txt.txt

Comment: @HarshavardhanKonakanchi Thank you so much!! It worked!! I didn't know that windows 10 hides extension by default and therefore included an extra .txt. Can't believe I spent hours on something so silly. Thanks for saving me!!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your kind help! really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code and it runs fine.

Try to use a directory with access rights, like your home folder.

> C:\TestData\data

Are you sure that you created a data.txt file and not a data (without extension) accidently?

Comment: I have included an snip shot of the location of my file and its name, I dont think I have left out the extension.

Comment: I tried the code by creating a text file (as the same position as you did), wrote one character, saved it. Run the code within eclipse and erverything worked fine. If it is not a problem with the path and you tried another location then I am realy out of ideas, sorry.
I think you did it already, but select the 'show file extension' option in the view tab of you explorer to show all file extensions. This way, you are able to avoid cases like Harshavardhan Konakanchi mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! the extra extension was indeed the problem. Really appreciate you taking time and helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

All known file extensions are hidden by default in windows

The problem I believe here to be is that you are not able to view the file extension. It can be viewed by unchecking `Hide extensions for known file types` in `Folder Options` > `View`